# In Next.js, how to init the app no matter the entering routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My app needs to load some global data into the Redux store upon app start. First I used a run once useEffect on the front page whose route is `/`

Now I'm adding new routes like `/user-profile`. If I directly type the url in browser to make it enter from the profile route, then the code to load data into the store in `/` won't be run. This is pretty understandable.

So my question is:

1. Is there some place I can put a app level init code no matter the entry routes. I don't want to copy paste the useEffect on every page component.
2. Is there something to be used to fetch some data before the app enters a route just like Angular's route resolver: https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new Next JS App Router, simply place your entry component in the Root Layout file `app/layout.tsx`, and it will trigger on any entry point